# Woocommerce Filter by price not widget not showing because of NOT taking woocommerce css

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Except shop page all other pages Filter by price widget not showing i checked , & found that this is not taking any css of woocomerce or even theme. so widget is coming but not showing.
Any help
Note: i have up to date wooomerce.
Thanks

Comment: please check that your wp theme is supporting woocomerce or not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit your theme/child theme's `header.php` and add the class `woocommerce` to the `body` element yourself.